# What should be the debounce time for the diagnosis of short circuit to ground?

Tags: short-circuit, debounce

There is an analog input voltage pin of a microcontroller whose threshold voltage is set 0.2V. If the input voltage at the pin is below 0.2V, then it is recognised as the short circuit to ground(SCG). A value for the debounced time should be chosen in ms. When the input voltage is below 0.2V for a time as long as the debounced time, then the error bit SCG is set.
Do you have an idea how i can calculate the optimum debounced time?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the problem. Most likely you know all about the system you are designing, but I don't. Please provide all the information you can, too much information will not hurt, but too little means noone can answer.

Comment: most microbutton switches 5ms

Comment: @ peufeu Thanks for the comment. - The problem is I do not know how to calculate the debounce time for debouncing a 'high' - the high comes when there is a short circuit to ground. A short circuit to ground(SCG) may come just for a few microseconds at the analog input pin and then vanish. An SCG for a few microseconds may not be enough to set the error bit SCG. So, how many seconds are enough to call it an SCG?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thanks. This debounce seems less relevant to switch debounce, so i haven't found any material on the net.

Comment: it depends what you are connected to

Comment: do you mean like the pull up/down voltages too?

Comment: Is this an ECU function? Then it means a faulty sensor short

Comment: Yes, its an ECU and a short circuit at a faulty sensor.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, in other words, the question is like, how long should the currect flow to ground, so that the ECU recognises as error.

Comment: I think so, which may be a long time in ms  e.g. 500ms  this spreadsheet shows some ECU fault detection parameters that may be useful http://www.dulevo.com/documenti/codici-guasto-5020e6.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCG is a common automotive ECU fault diagnostic function such as the O2 sensor which is a field replaceable part.

It may be a long time in ms e.g. 500ms but not too long to stall the engine.

this spreadsheet shows some ECU fault detection parameters that may be useful.

http://dulevo.com/documenti/codici-guasto-5020e6.xls

Comment: Tony, thanks for your answer and the document. :-)

Comment: Hello Tony, are there other parameters which help to calculate the exact value of the debounce time? For example, the open pin voltage of the pin - that the debounce time for SCG should be 
kept shorter if the voltage gets larger.